# facebook integration with java

Tags: java, jquery, facebook, jsp

I am creating jsp application with jQuery. I want to create one link.if I click on that link it shows next 5 posts of Facebook. But I don't know how to do. Here is my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    //if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>= $(document).height())
    {
        //var next=5;   
        var id = $("#postCountId").val();
        alert(id);
        var dataString = 'searchword=' + id;
        //var dataString={nextrecord:next};
        alert(dataString);
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "actpost_ajax.jsp",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                alert("inside success here");
                if (html) {

                    alert("inside html " + id);
                    $("#wall-post-main").append(html);
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                    $('#postCountId').val(+$('#postCountId').val() + 5);

                    $('#postCountId').hide();
                } else {
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to integrate from here.

[FACEBOOK API](https://developers.facebook.com/)

here you ll get snippet code, and API's how to deal with access token.